# Clone method on java interface

Tags: java, interface, clone

I have following problem;

I have inerface with public method clone():

```
public interface Something {
    Something clone();
}
```

and also

```
public class SomethingImpl implements Something {

        private Something some;

    public Something clone() {
        return some.clone();
    }
}
```

Whenewer I run from code somewhere

```
...
Something i =  new SomethingImpl();
...
// do something on i
...
someMethod(i);
...

public void someMethod(Something some){
    Something some2 = some.clone(); 
  }
```

I get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException on line Someting some2 = some.clone;

I programmed a lot bussiness logic, but never till now I encountered neccessity of cloning, esspecially this way.

Can someone point me in which direction I should go? I tried to read articles on this topic but just got more confused.

Thanks in advance,
Mile

Comment: I don't see `Something` having a (static & final) `clone` field.

Comment: And how does this even compile? Please post all your code.

Comment: I suspect the exception is in the SomethingImpl.clone() method because the `some` field is never initialized. Anyway... what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A method and a field are two different things. `clone` is a field, which is not defined and hence will not exist. `clone()` is a method. Did you mean `Someting some2 = some.clone()`?

**Edit** I just saw your actual error (although what I said above should still be heeded!). This means that `some` must be `null` - are you perhaps changing its value in the portions of code you omitted? Be sure to check for that whenever you receive a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: That wouldn't explain the null pointer. His exception means `some` was null. The error you describe he hasn't even encountered yet.

Comment: I don't even get how this compiles.

Comment: I think the `some.clone` is a typo created when he copy/pasted the code somehow.

Comment: some.clone should be some.clone(); it's typing mistake.
Also interface has some other methods - not only clone, but it all works, just this cloning is giving me headache. Sorry if I am not clear, but this is the best I could describe my problem.

Comment: Also - some that is passed to method is not null

Comment: The `NullPointerException` occurs on the line `Someting some2 = some.clone()`, the only thing that could cause this would be `some` being null.

Comment: Thanks all for answers... yeah, for my stupidity only sky is border :) null in one getter method equaled what I passed to null.. and my smart ass overlooked that small step.. Thank all once again - it works :)

Answer (score 1):

Given your example, the only way

```
public void someMethod(Something some){
    Something some2 = some.clone(); 
}
```

can throw a `NullPointerException` is if you pass null to `someMethod(Something some)`.

Comment: some in someMethod(Something some) is not null - thats ok, but when I call .clone() on it - clone method returns null or in some cases when I call
` public Something clone(){
  
  try {
   return (Something) super.clone();
  } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return some /* local - private Something some; */;
 }`
retrns CloneNotSupportedException ... :(

Sorry, I cant find way to insert `code` in comment